# are my environment variables secure from other users on the system?

Tags: linux, security, shell

I hope the system doesn't matter as long as it's current, but I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 Server. Is there any way for any user y to see user x's environment variables? In other words, is it safe to store a password in an environment variable during an install script -- assuming that the user running the software is allowed to know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to access environment variables reading file `/proc/*PID*/environ`. But it has the same credentials as the process it concerns to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's possible to capture passwords stored in memory using a memory dump. To minimize risks, password management tools overwrite memory (i.e. clipboard) after a few seconds.

Edit: Searching in the internet I've found an example of this technique in ubuntu [here](http://steeve-barbeau.blogspot.com/2011/03/get-password-from-memory-dump.html).